# Correct usage of "of which"

Tags: phrases, pronouns

> I have two books, *of which* one is borrowed.

Is this correct? Is there such a phrase?

Comment: Please support the proposed site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's grammatically correct, although it would be more usual to say "I have two books, one of which is borrowed".

Comment: Thanks @Christi , I agree "one of which" does sound more usual. I think that is why I doubted `of which` was correct in my construction.

Comment: I would use 'of which one...' only if I were then going on to say something about the other(s). Example: I have two books, of which one is mine and one is borrowed.

Comment: "one of which is mine" would also work in that context.  "The bank across the street, of which I am the manager, is up for sale" could not be rephrased in the same way, but I must confess I am at a loss as to the rule which means only the inverted form is appropriate in this final case.

Comment: It's grammatical, but unlikely in authentic speech. What you would probably hear would be something like 'Yeh, I've got these two books, see? They're not both mine though. I borrowed one from a mate.'

Comment: @Christi: the difference is that _one_ is the subject of the relative clause, but _the manager_ isn't . _The bank across the street, the manager of which is a friend of mine, ..._ is grammatical, if stilted.

Comment: @Christi "The bank across the street, the manager of which is myself, is up for sale."