# Usage / examples of "of which"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

Could anyone give me some examples or rules for using `", of which"`? I mean only `", of which"`, neither `"which"` nor `", xxx of which"`. Any idea is appreciated.

p.s. *She discovered so many spiders, of which she was most afraid.* - Cool Elf

Is it possible, that *"of"* is not an essential part of the verb in the relative clause?

Comment: Welcome, macio.Jun. I'm afraid questions where each answer is equally valid are considered not constructive. Perhaps you could edit your question to require a concrete answer. Please read the [faq] for more information.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, macio; you might be interested in reading this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/correct-usage-of-of-which

Comment: Thank you Matt, but I can't really find one meaningful usage for ", of which". Thank you Carlo_R, that thread only discusses the usage of ", xxx of which".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"*Of which*" is part of a **relative clause**.

"*Which*" is the relative pronoun and "*of*" is a preposition placed at the beginning of the relative clause, instead of at the end.

A few examples of this construction are:

> 1. She discovered so many spiders, **of which** she was most afraid.
> 2. He answered all the listening and reading exercises, **of which** the test mostly consisted.
> 3. The team won a silver medal, **of which** they were very proud.

Note also that you can place "*of*" differently:

> 1. She discovered so many spiders, **which** she was most afraid **of**.
> 2. He answered all the listening and reading exercises, **which** the test mostly consisted **of**.
> 3. The team won a silver medal, **which** they were very proud **of**.

Comment: Cool Elf, Thank you for your concrete explanation. But I am sure that I've seen some other cases, under which "of" is not an essential part of the verb in the conditoin sentence.

Comment: the **of which** construction is often used to avoid ending a sentence with a preposition. This long standing rule seems to be fading.

Comment: Hi macio.Jun. How about "There were three books, of which the blue one was the thickest"?

Comment: This is equivalent to "There were three books, the blue one of which was the thickest".

Comment: @macio.Jun "There were three books, and the blue one of which was the thickest."

Comment: "The book, of which the pages were torn, was blue.". No way to place "of" somewhere else, right?