# Correct use of 'of which'

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, possessive-of-which

So, I happened to be reading a grammar book in which I came across this weird looking sentence.

> This is the car of which parts are not available now.

I think it should have been something like this:

> This is the car, parts of which are not available now.

If the improvised version is correct, I do not know why. Can you guys help me with such constructions?

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the book and the context in which you found this sentence?

Comment: Assuming you're only interested in the position of "of which", see e.g. [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/correct-usage-of-of-which): both are correct, although "parts of which" (or "whose parts") is more common and to me "of which parts" sounds too formal for what's presumably a car manual or something similar. There are many similar questions if you search for *of which*.

Comment: With reference to a car, _parts_ has the particular meaning 'replacement parts of the engine', while _parts of which_ sounds more general. I think it would have been better expressed as _the car_ **for** _which parts are not available_.

Comment: In support of @KateBunting it's far more likely to be "for" than "of."  If someone says that sentence to you, and you don't know why, a correct response would be to ask "why do you need parts of that car?"  If your interlocutor says "I don't need parts _of_ the car; I need parts _for_ the car," then the first sentence should have used "for which" rather than "of which."  Aside: the punctuation of your second sentence is incorrect; there should be no comma. The more colloquial rendering is "this is the car that you can't get parts for now" (a construction long frowned upon by prescriptivists).

Comment: @L Lawliet  What grammar book is that? I would suggest "This is the car whose parts are not available now.

Comment: 'This is the car of which parts are not available now.' is grammatically correct but would need unusual context to make sense, and be very formal. Without a comma, the of-clause is specifying ('defining'), **identifying** the car in question. With the comma (although your rewrite sounds more natural), the of-clause would be non-specifying, 'merely' adding additional information about the car being referred to.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, this is the confusion that arises when people lack the moral courage to use *whose* correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your version is correct; the grammar book’s is not.

This is from *The Chicago Manual of Style*:

> **5: Grammar and Usage**
> **5.64: “Whose” and “of which”**
>  The relatives *who* and *which* can both take *whose* as a possessive form (*whose* substitutes for
> *of which*) {a movie the conclusion **of which** is unforgettable} {a movie **whose** conclusion is unforgettable}.
>  <sub>Source: [The
> Chicago Manual of
> Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch05/psec064.html)</sub>

You can compare these to see how the possessive relative construction works:

> This is a movie the conclusion **[of which]** is
> unforgettable. —>
>
> This is a movie the conclusion **[of this movie]** is
> unforgettable. —>
>
> This is a movie **[whose]** conclusion is unforgettable.
>
> This is the car, parts **[of which]** are not available now. —>
>
> This is the car, parts **[of this car]** are not available now. —>
>
> This is the car **[whose]** parts are not available now.

Here’s what’s wrong with the book’s version:

> *This is the car **[of which]** parts are not available now. —>
>
> *This is the car **[of this car]** parts are not available now. —>

PS: The *CMOS* entry continues:

> Some writers object to using *whose* as a replacement for *of which*,
> especially when the subject is not human, but the usage is centuries
> old and is widely accepted as preventing unnecessary awkwardness.
> Compare *the company whose stock rose faster* with *the company the
> stock of which rose faster*. Either form is acceptable, but the
> possessive *whose* is far smoother.

PPS: In your example, even if *parts of which...* is an essential clause, it nonetheless needs a “comma of clarity” between *car* and *parts* to prevent a read of *car parts*.

Answer (score -3):

There is a very subtle difference between the two in some regions, like my region in the Southern United States.

> This is the car, parts of which are not available now.

Would imply that the parts are the parts of the car, such that the car was disassembled, the parts were moved, and a few of the parts were lost.

> This is the char, of which parts are not available now.

Implies that the parts are "of the car" meaning they are representatives of parts that car might have, but aren't directly the parts the car had.  In other words, it implies that one has a whole car, but replacement parts are not available now.

There is very little that indicates this is a common way of reading these two sentences beyond my local region; but, it does explain why some areas still use "of which" when other areas see it only as a way of speaking more formally.

Comment: Please cite sources for this claim about a potential difference in meaning, in your region/dialect or anywhere else. I doubt that most others, even in your area, perceive a similar difference.

Comment: Then come on over and ask my neighbors :)   Sorry for the joke, but it is not possibly to authoritatively prove what another thinks, unless you're that other person.  I'm just reporting how people react when we use one phrase as opposed to the other.

Comment: You may well be right, but you need to cite sources for that, other than just your intuitions about how you think people react.